# reverse the order of the linked list

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a linkedlist, which add an object like a tree, the following is the printout
LinkedList nodeList = new LinkedList();

(result A)

```
1 : Tester Meeting
2 : Adminstrative & Operational 
3 : Functional Committees
4 : Aduit Committee
9 :    Supporting Services Development
8 :    Medical Services Development 
7 :    Information Technology Services 
6 :    Human Resources Committee
15 :          test2-2
14 :       test2
13 :          test1-1
12 :       test1
5 :    Finance Committee
10 : Regional Advisory Committees
11 : Board Workshop
```

(result B)The following should be the right order

```
Tester Meeting
Adminstrative & Operational 
Functional Committees
Aduit Committee
   Finance Committee
      test1
         test1-1
      test2
         test2-2
   Human Resources Committee
   Information Technology Services 
   Medical Services Development 
   Supporting Services Development
Regional Advisory Committees
Board Workshop
```

So, i want to reverse the order of sub-node of Audit Committee of (ResultA) output the result of same as the ResultB, is there any method to sort the specific node of linked list?

Comment: A LinkedList is not a Tree, so how is a 'sub-node' implemented?

Comment: It is not a question of ordering the tree, rather it is how you walk the tree.

Comment: A LinkedList does not Sort very well, any reason you do not use a List<> ?

Comment: @Henk Holterman there is unknown numbers of nested node

Answer (score 2):

No. The linked list has not concept of a sort order other than the order that the items were created. It's meant to be fast for traversing and adding many items. I am not sure that this data structure suits your needs at all.

I am not sure what your requirements are. Maybe if you could list the requirements we could make some suggestions.

Comment: there is unknown numbers of nested node, is there any other data structure is suitable?

Comment: A tree will be able to support that. Just make sure you don't find any sort of balanced tree. These trees automatically adjust themselves to make sure that no level in the tree can differ from the height of the tree by more than 1. This is for performance. So you would need a tree that preserves its structure.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing a Tree structure looks more suitable.

It is about tree traversal. It is about whether you traverse the children from left to right or from right to left:

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Node rootNode = new Node();
        rootNode.Name = "root";
        Node node1 = new Node();
        node1.Name = "child 1";

```
    Node node2 = new Node();
    node2.Name = "child 2";

    rootNode.Children.Add(node1);
    rootNode.Children.Add(node2);

    Node node3 = new Node();
    node3.Name = "child 3";



    node1.Children.Add(node3);


    Traverse(rootNode);

    Console.WriteLine("Reverse: ");

    TraverseReverse(rootNode);

}

private static void Traverse(Node node)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
    for (int index = 0; index < node.Children.Count;index++ )
    {
        Traverse(node.Children[index]);
    }            
}

private static void TraverseReverse(Node node)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
    for (int index = node.Children.Count-1; index >=0; index--)
    {
        TraverseReverse(node.Children[index]);
    }
}
```

}

Output:

```
root
child 1
child 3
child 2
Reverse:
root
child 2
child 1
child 3
```